# shibboleth saml response attributes not is servervariables in Application_PostAuthenticateRequest

Tags: c#, saml, shibboleth

scenario:
1.
"Host name="sp.edu"  authType="shibboleth" scheme="http" requireSession="true">
    "

2. when pinged back with /Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST, Chrome shows saml response data and all the attributes declared in the attribute-map.xml
3. in Application_PostAuthenticateRequest I loop through Request.ServerVariables 
   but the attributes in the saml response are not there!

any insight will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i also loop through the Headers

Comment: IIS version 8.5 mvc5 VS 2015

Comment: here is how shibboleth access host:   <Host name="mctest-local.med.miami.edu"  authType="shibboleth" scheme="http" requireSession="true">
   </Host>